¿Cuál es la diferencia entre los algoritmos de búsqueda binaria y lineal, y cuándo es más eficiente usar uno sobre el otro?
Tengo que estudiar algoritmos, pero lo que no entiendo es cuando debo usar algoritmos de búsqueda binaria y cuando usar algoritmos de búsqueda lineal
Entiendo cómo funciona cada una y que, en el caso de la búsqueda binaria, necesito que la lista esté ordenada. Mi duda es, ¿La búsqueda binaria la utilizo cuando la lista esté ordenada y sino la lineal?
¿Por qué no uso siempre la lineal?

Y que buscaste de cada uno? que entendiste de cada uno? que hace cada uno?

Entiendo como funciona cada una y que en el caso de la busqueda binaria, necesito que la lista esté ordenada. Mi duda es, ¿La busqueda binaria la utilizo cuando la lista esté ordenada y sino la lineal? ¿Por qué no uso siempre la lineal?

por qué no siempre la lineal? porque si vas a hacer muchas búsquedas es por lo general mas conveniente ordenar una vez y usar la binaria muchas veces que usar la lineal muchas veces. dependiendo de la situacion y el corpus de data tal vez ordenar sea prohibitivo o efímero

La búsqueda binaria es más rápida (O(log n)) en listas ordenadas, mientras que la lineal (O(n)) se usa en listas no ordenadas. Usa binaria cuando la lista está ordenada.
